# How can i publish any module publicly on BitBucket as gredle dependency?

Tags: java, android, github, kotlin, bitbucket

i need to publish my module on BitBucket as gredle dependency.
like "implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'".
i achieved this using Github. But my code is on Bitbucket and need to achieve this on BitBucket.
i want to share only my gredle dependency instead of module .aar or .jar file. User can sync every-time with new version when any update available on BitBucket. Can anyone please help me for this?